# Pentaho, multiple outputs for multiple inputs

Tags: excel, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have been trying to figure out how to set Pentaho to write DIFFERENT files for each input of the job.

My transformation will soon be able to fetch .txt files from an FTP, a varying number of files, the way my transformation is right now, whatever the number of files it gets from the folder(FTP or local) it is generating one big XLS output, the information in the output side is all correct, it all matches the data i want to extract with precision, but for organizing those files, i need pentaho to create a single file, from a single input.

If files (//PentahoIn0001.txt, //PentahoIn0002.txt, //PentahoIn0003.txt) are processed i want (//PentahoOut0001.xls, //PentahoOut0002.xls, //PentahoOut0003.xls) to be created, and the way it is right now it's only creating a single file with data worth of all three inputs.

So far i have tried several ways with no result, even posts from here and outside containing several other aid Transformations and jobs to do it, and it simply doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the output filename in the row, and making sure the rows are sorted on the filename call `Transformation Executor` with a new transformation that should save the data. Make sure to enable `Row grouping` on the filename field, and also pass the filename as a `Parameter` to the new transformation.

In the child transformation start with `Get rows from result` and save the result to the file using the passed filename parameter.

Comment: It sort of work but for a different purpose, i tried it in my transformation / jobs but now the problem is, im setting a variable in the job with a piece of the source filename, which is extracted in another transformation: